# Tile based game. Fixing surface issue for attack

Tags: python, pygame

So far I've loaded the images and can move the sprite around. When I hit the spacebar to cycle through the attack sprites within the `attack_front` list. The image becomes compressed, because the sword is now extending outwards. How would I go about keeping the image in the same location and only extending the surface I print it on for these images? I've tried just adjusting the surface in my get_image method, but the image skips around on the screen when you move.

I've made a gist and uploaded the spritesheet I'm utilizing to imgur and the links are below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame as pg
from settings import *

class Spritesheet:

def __init__(self, filename):
    self.spritesheet = pg.image.load(filename).convert()

def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
    image = pg.Surface((width, height)) #tried resizing this to specifc w & h, but made image skip around
    image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))

    image = pg.transform.scale(image, (150,150))
    return image

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.walking = False
        self.standing = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(9, 108, 18, 23)
        self.load_images()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.x = -3
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x = 3
        if keys[pg.K_UP]:
            self.y = -3
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN]:
            self.y = 3

        self.rect.x += self.x
        self.rect.y += self.y

    def load_images(self):
        self.standing = {'front': self.game.spritesheet.get_image(9, 108, 18, 23),
                         'back': self.game.spritesheet.get_image(79, 10, 17, 21),
                         'right': self.game.spritesheet.get_image(8, 190, 18, 21)}

        self.standing_left = []


        self.walking_bck = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(106, 108, 18, 23),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(138, 109, 18, 22),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(170, 107, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(200, 107, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(232, 107, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(263, 108, 18, 23),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(296, 109, 18, 22),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(328, 107, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(360, 107, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(391, 107, 18, 24)]

        self.walking_fwd = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(103, 189, 18, 22),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(136, 189, 18, 22),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(168, 187, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(200, 186, 18, 25),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(230, 187, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(262, 189, 18, 22),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(293, 189, 18, 22),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(326, 187, 18, 24),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(360, 186, 18, 25),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(390, 187, 18, 24)]

        self.walking_right = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(100, 151, 23, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(134, 152, 20, 21),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(168, 152, 20, 21),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(199, 151, 20, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(229, 151, 20, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(258, 151, 23, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(292, 151, 19, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(327, 151, 19, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(360, 151, 19, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(389, 151, 20, 22),]

        self.walking_left = []
        for frame in self.walking_right:
            self.walking_left.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))

        self.attack_front = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(0, 229, 28, 22),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(38, 228, 25, 25),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(80, 227, 19, 33),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(114, 227, 19, 34),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(151, 228, 25, 33),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(193, 227, 29, 32),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(238, 227, 31, 24),
                             self.game.spritesheet.get_image(285, 228, 32, 23),]


    def animate(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if self.x or self.y != 0:
            self.walking = True
        else:
            self.walking = False

        if self.walking:
            if now - self.last_update > 100:
                self.last_update = now
                #bottom = self.rect.bottom
                if keys[pg.K_DOWN]:
                    self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walking_bck)
                    self.image = self.walking_bck[self.current_frame]

                if keys[pg.K_UP]:
                    self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walking_fwd)
                    self.image = self.walking_fwd[self.current_frame]

                if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
                    self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walking_left)
                    self.image = self.walking_left[self.current_frame]

                if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walking_right)
                    self.image = self.walking_right[self.current_frame]


        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.attack_front)
            self.image = self.attack_front[self.current_frame]
```

Code: https://gist.github.com/crushedhat/95ab270d723a8d7fb45721f1cad93ee4 
Spritesheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMKLQ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to normalize all your animation frames so that they are the same size. That way, your player's rect never changes and in your game's `draw()` method you can always just render the player's image at the player's `rect` without having to worry about variable sizes. Use a rect size that can accommodate the largest animation frame you have. This is what I do when I use Pygame.

If you're worried about such a large rect giving you problems with collision and so on—don't. You can define a `bounding_rect` object for your player with which to calculate collisions. The bounding rect should be significantly smaller than the rect and should sit inside it.

I would also suggest creating a position attribute, `pos`, for your `Player` class. This is what you should change when you do input processing. It's your `pos` attribute which changes when you press a direction key. Your `bounding_rect` will simply follow your position, and the larger `rect` you're using for blitting images will simply follow your bounding rect.

Here's an image:

[image]

And here's some example code:

```
if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        self.pos.x = -3 .                                   # update position
        self.bounding_rect.centerx = self.pos.x             # the bounding rect is centered at your position
        self.rect.midbottom = self.bounding_rect.midbottom  # the rect you use to blit the image simply follows along
```